# How to set to 0.0 a default value of a decimal column

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have an existing migration with no default values set in decimal columns:

```
class CreateOperations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :operations do |t|
      t.integer :account_id
      t.string :operation_type
      t.date :value_date
      t.date :close_date
      t.decimal :sum, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :rate, precision: 5, scale: 2
      t.decimal :withholding, precision: 5, scale: 2
      t.integer :duration
      t.decimal :interests, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :total, precision: 10, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When creating an `Operation`, the values of non-mandatory decimal attributes are set to `nil`. How is it possible to set them to `0.0`? I tried to add `default: 0.0`to the existing migration as follows:

```
class CreateOperations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :operations do |t|
      t.integer :account_id
      t.string :operation_type
      t.date :value_date
      t.date :close_date
      t.decimal :sum, precision: 10, scale: 2, default: 0.0
      t.decimal :rate, precision: 5, scale: 2, default: 0.0
      t.decimal :withholding, precision: 5, scale: 2, default: 0.0
      t.integer :duration default: 0
      t.decimal :interests, precision: 10, scale: 2, default: 0.0
      t.decimal :total, precision: 10, scale: 2, default: 0.0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and run `rails db:reset`(just to test it locally) but it still sets to `nil` these values. What's wrong with that?

I'm using:

- Rails 5.2.3
- Ruby 2.6.1
- Postgresql 9.6.10
- pg gem, '~> 1.1.4

Thank you.

Comment: If you have not specified NOT NULL to your column definition then I would presume that the data that is being inserted through the migration originally was a NULL (or Nil) and therefore it is just a reflection of the original set.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the existing migration hasn't solved the problem, even after resetting the database.
I had to create a new migration and use `change_column_default` method as follows:

```
class ChangeOperationDecimalDefaultValues < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column_default(:operations, :sum, from: nil, to: 0.0)
    change_column_default(:operations, :rate, from: nil, to: 0.0)
    change_column_default(:operations, :withholding, from: nil, to: 0.0)
    change_column_default(:operations, :interests, from: nil, to: 0.0)
    change_column_default(:operations, :total, from: nil, to: 0.0)
  end
end
```

After running the migration, `schema.rb` was also updated and the problem was fixed.
Initially, the problem was detected when migrating from Ruby 2.4.0 to 2.6.1 version. With Ruby 2.4.0 there was no this problem.

The following code raised an error because of null values of `total`:

```
...
except_remissions     = deposits_and_withdrawals(operations)
sum_except_remissions = except_remissions.map(&:total).inject(:+) || 0


...
def deposits_and_withdrawals(ops)
  ops.select {|op| op.operation_type != Operation::REMISSION }
end
```

Hope this helps.